# Angular6, Cannot pre-define styleUrls

Tags: angular, components

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
const urls = ['./app.component.css'];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: urls
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'multi-css-app';
}
```

This ends up with an error like the following
[image]

Does anyone know why?

The reason I am trying to do this way is to determine which css file I want to use before component is built. e.g. style.a.css for this app, and style.b.css for different app.

FYI: I am using Angular6

Answer (score 0):

In case, if you want to use only one css file, instead of passing an array, you can pass only the string or the link to the css file like -

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
const urls = './app.component.css';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [urls]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'multi-css-app';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am giving the answer by an example you can change as per your requirement as I don't know your conditions.

Example

```
import { Component, OnInit, isDevMode } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 
  cssUrl: string;
 
  constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
 
  }
 
  ngOnInit() {
    const randomIntegerInRange = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
 
    const n = randomIntegerInRange(1, 100) % 2;
    this.cssUrl = n % 2 === 0 ? '/assets/styles1.css' : '/assets/styles2.css';
  }
 
}
```

The code shown above does the following:

- It implements OnInit lifecycle hook. This hook is called before the component is rendered.
- We set the cssUrl value to styles1.css if the number is even else we set
  it to styles2.css.
- Next, we need to create two CSS files in the assets directory. The advantage of keeping CSS in the assets directory is that they will
  not be packaged in the application package. Thus, keeping package
  size in check.

**Now that we have created the style files. We just need to update app.component.html to use the cssUrl property.**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" [href]='sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(cssUrl)'>
 
<h1>Working with dynamic CSS loading -:)</h1>
```

We have to use Angular’s DomSanitizer sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(cssUrl) to tell Angular that the URL is safe to use. If you don’t do it then Angular will give you an error.

```
Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context
```